# How to find, what error in spring MVC/JDO at runtime on Eclipse kepler is really because of library missing or program mistake

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jdo

"Since I am new to Spring MVCand JDO"

"I have no idea what reason for error"

"This much of error message come I have no idea how to find the error"

"after all my mentor came once and clear the for hello world mvc and said because of library"

"I am new to spring and jdo so I have no idea what lib it needed there and what not will need at the program even though I am working at eclipse I have to download or borrow library for my program manually...."

"but I used a program for java data object using mvc spring framework with correction of previous error so called library missing."

it show like this..
and I believe The eclipse automatically include library for JDO: Java Data Object through GAE
so I guess it not be because of JDO lib and I already used

Spring lib I used:

```
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\user\Personnal\Software\eclipse\springs lib SDK 1.9.9\spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

lib folder contains commonly in war path:

```
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.9.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.9.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/asm-4.0.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.2.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
/jdo/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

MY console show me like this:

---

```
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed D:\eclipse workspace\jdo\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed D:\eclipse workspace\jdo\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:31 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'D:\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.9\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.9\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'D:\eclipse workspace\jdo\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:31 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:36 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher'
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization started
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:36 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Sep 27 13:01:36 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:36 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:39 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:41 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:41 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1080b7fd: defining beans [personcontroller,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1080b7fd: defining beans [personcontroller,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personcontroller' defined in file [D:\eclipse workspace\jdo\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\web\project\Personcontroller.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.web.project.Personcontroller]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.web.project.Personcontroller]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.web.project.Personcontroller.<init>(Personcontroller.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
NestedThrowables:
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:861)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at pmf.PMF.<clinit>(PMF.java:6)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:441)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    ... 65 more

Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personcontroller' defined in file [D:\eclipse workspace\jdo\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\web\project\Personcontroller.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.web.project.Personcontroller]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.web.project.Personcontroller]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$4.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:999)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at com.web.project.Personcontroller.<init>(Personcontroller.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
NestedThrowables:
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:861)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1099)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:919)
    at pmf.PMF.<clinit>(PMF.java:6)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:441)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:844)
    ... 65 more

Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Sep 27, 2014 1:01:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

and my web result : HTTP ERROR 500 Powered by Jetty://

Comment: "javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name" is very explicit. You don't have a persistence-unit defined with that name

Comment: no I have been specified and used transaction-optional in PMF

Comment: package pmf;

import javax.jdo.*;

public final class PMF {
 private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
 private PMF(){
  
 }
 public static PersistenceManagerFactory get()
 {
  return pmfInstance;
 }
 
}

Comment: so why can't it find one then? persistence.xml in wrong place? invalid persistence.xml ? they are the only options and you provide no info for anyone to say which it is

Comment: SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 29; The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398) and so on....

Comment: any idea ? about this issue sir ?

Comment: The exception in your post is about the persistence.xml being wrong/invalid (the cause exception). That is what my comments address.  If you now have something else you put that in a different question

Answer (score 1):

`javax.jdo.JDOUserException: PersistenceManagerFactory has been specified to use "persistence-unit" with name "transaction-optional" but none was found with that name"` is very explicit. You either have persistence.xml in the wrong place (should be under META-INF at the root of the CLASSPATH), or it doesn't contain that persistence-unit, or is invalidly formatted.